# import sqllite3 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sqllite3' on Windows 10

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to create Sqllite database using Python. I am using python 3.6 version and working on a windows 10 pc.

I successfully installed pysqlite3

```
 pip install pysqlite3
```

But I am facing issue when I am trying to run my code as below

```
import sqllite3

conn = sqllite3.connect('Stock.db')
c=conn.cursor()
```

I am receiving the following error.

```
import sqllite3
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sqllite3'
```

I saw solutions for ubuntu and Linux machines has anyone faced the same problem for window machine before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your `import` statement. The module should be `sqlite3` instead of `sqllite3`.